# How to Send Parcel on click Recyler view with Sqlite Database

Tags: android, android-intent, android-database

I have entered my data using **sqlite**, but when I  want to use parcel inside **recyler** view using intent in which I am confused how do I get the adapter position to store into bundle and send it through intent to other activity and collect it in other activity..

**Here is my code,**

**my model class with parcel**

```
 public class FamousPeople implements Parcelable {
private static final String FAMOUS_NAME = "famous name";
private static final String FAMOUS_PHOTO="photo";

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

private long id;
private String name;
private String photo;
private String details;




public String getDetails() {
    return details;
}


public void setDetails(String details) {
    this.details = details;
}


public String getPhoto() {
    return photo;
}


public void setPhoto(String photo) {
    this.photo = photo;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}


public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeLong(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.photo);
    dest.writeString(this.details);
}

public FamousPeople() {
}

protected FamousPeople(Parcel in) {
    this.id = in.readLong();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.photo = in.readString();
    this.details = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<FamousPeople> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<FamousPeople>() {
    @Override
    public FamousPeople createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new FamousPeople(source);
    }

    @Override
    public FamousPeople[] newArray(int size) {
        return new FamousPeople[size];
    }
};
}
```

My fragment where I am  using **sqlite database**

```
public class BiographyFragment extends Fragment {

StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggeredGridLayoutManager;
List<FamousPeople> famousPeoples;
BiographyDataSource biographyDataSource;

public BiographyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    biographyDataSource=new BiographyDataSource(getActivity());
    biographyDataSource.open();
    Log.v("data","database created");
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_biography, container, false);
    RecyclerView recyclerView= (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    staggeredGridLayoutManager=new
            StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
    List<FamousPeople> famousPeoples=biographyDataSource.findRecords();
    List<FamousPeople> famousPeopleArrayList=biographyDataSource.findRecords();
    if(famousPeoples.size()==0){
        BioData bioData=new BioData();
        bioData.createdata();
        famousPeoples=biographyDataSource.findRecords();


    }
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerViewAdapter=
            new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(),famousPeoples);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewAdapter);


    return view;
}


 }
```

** My data list through which I am collecting data **

```
  public class BioData 
    {

    List<FamousPeople> famousPeoples;
    BiographyDataSource biographyDataSource;
   public List<FamousPeople> createdata(){
    FamousPeople famousPeople=new FamousPeople();
    famousPeople.setName("rahul");
    famousPeople.setPhoto("amitabh");
    famousPeople.setDetails("hello this is amitabh");
    biographyDataSource.create(famousPeople);
    Log.v("data", "inserted value 1");
    famousPeople=new FamousPeople();
    famousPeople.setName("cvraman");
    famousPeople.setPhoto("cvraman");
    famousPeople.setDetails("hello this is amitabh");
    biographyDataSource.create(famousPeople);
    Log.v("data", "inserted value 2");
    famousPeople=new FamousPeople();
    famousPeople.setName("indira");
    famousPeople.setPhoto("indira");
    famousPeople.setDetails("hello this is amitabh");
    biographyDataSource.create(famousPeople);
    Log.v("data", "inserted value 3");
    famousPeople=new FamousPeople();
    famousPeople.setName("modi");
    famousPeople.setPhoto("modi");
    famousPeople.setDetails("hello this is amitabh");
    biographyDataSource.create(famousPeople);
    Log.v("data", "inserted value 4");
    return famousPeoples;
}
}
```

My **recyler** view where I am confused to use parcel which collect the position on click and send the appropriate dat to other Activity

```
 class BiographyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    implements View.OnClickListener {

 public TextView textView;
  public ImageView imageView;
  BiographyDataSource biographyDataSource;
List<FamousPeople> famousPeoples;


public BiographyViewHolder(View itemView)
{
    super(itemView);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    textView= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);
    imageView= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_photo);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    List<FamousPeople> famousPeopleArrayList=biographyDataSource.findRecords();
    if(famousPeoples.size()==0){
        BioData bioData=new BioData();
        bioData.createdata();
        famousPeoples=biographyDataSource.findRecords();


    }
    Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
   // bundle.putParcelable("test",famousPeopleArrayList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
    Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),DetailActivity.class);
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**i got the answer by making the inner class i read the principal on java docs**

```
**java principal of inner class**
```

It is a way of logically grouping classes that are only used in one place: If a class is useful to only one other class, then it is logical to embed it in that class and keep the two together. Nesting such "helper classes" makes their package more streamlined.

It increases encapsulation: Consider two top-level classes, A and B, where B needs access to members of A that would otherwise be declared private. By hiding class B within class A, A's members can be declared private and B can access them. In addition, B itself can be hidden from the outside world.

**i made the inner class inside biography fragment ,which is recyler view beacuse both are logically connected..**